# What is the best practice when manipulating 2D Vector of Strings?

Tags: rust

I need to store a 2D grid of strings of random size. I'm struggling to manipulate the vectors. Here's what I did:

```
let mut grid: Vec<&mut Vec<String>> = Vec::new();
let mut v0: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
let mut v1: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

v0.push("first string into v0".to_string());
v1.push("first string into v1".to_string());

grid.push(&mut v0); // in position 0
grid.push(&mut v1);

println!("{:?}", &grid);
```

And it returns (as expected):

```
[["first string into v0"], ["first string into v1"]]
```

Later on, I want to add a string to v0:

```
let t1 = grid.get_mut(0);
let t2 = t1.unwrap();
t2.push("A new string into v0".to_string());

println!("{:?}", &grid);
```

The output is then:

```
[["first string into v0", "A new string into v0"], ["first string into v1"]]
```

So, it worked but is it the optimal solution when using a 2D vector?

Comment: Why `Vec<&mut Vec<String>>` instead of `Vec<Vec<String>>`?

Comment: best practice is to avoid them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing everything almost right. The first question that comes to mind is why you're using a `Vec<&mut Vec<String>>`. In that case, the vecs v0 and v1 have to outlive the grid, which is not necessarily a great idea. I would suggest a `Vec<Vec<String>>`.

Joel Berkeley suggests in his answer that you could flatten the Vector, but he doesn't explain why you would want to do that in a grid. The reason is that rust 2D Vectors will always point to other vectors, making the CPU take two indirections to get to the real data, which is bad for cache-locality, which depending on what you're doing you may care or not about. If you're writing really high-performance code you would want to do that, but also depending on the kind of application you're designing you shouldn't [pre-optimize your code beforehand](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).

I would also suggest using the [`vec!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec.html) macro to define your vectors if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you plan to do with it (i.e. what 'optimal' means here), but if you know the expected size of your grid, you could flatten your `Vec`. Instead of a n-length `Vec` containing m-length `&mut Vec<String>`s, you could use a single (n x m)-length `Vec<&mut String>` then work out where the equivalent indices would be, e.g. instead of `grid[2][5]`, you'd `grid[2*m + 5]`.

You'd need either a sentinel to signify unassigned: perhaps `""`, or you could `Vec<&mut Option<String>>` and use `None`.